# Stanford Calculator doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I have a problem with the calculator app I made while I watched the Stanford course about swift. Overtime I try to do a calculation like cos, sin, sqrt in the calculator the program stops and it shows me the debugger. I'm new to swift and in generell iOS Development, here is the code where the Thread breakpoint is

```
func performOperationForOneNumber(symbol: String, operation: (Double) -> Double) {
        if operandStack.count >= 1 {
            let value = operandStack.removeLast()
            displayValue = operation(value)
            enter()
            switch symbol{
                case "x²": history.text = " (\(value))² ="
                default: history.text = symbol + " \(value) ="
            }
        }
    }
```

the error appears at `if operandStack.count >= 1` and on the stack is only 1 Double.

What do I need to change?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Very strange, now it works without a problem... I haven't changed something thou..

Comment: Anyway in general, if you are learning from scratch, the use of beta versions could be more then a problem for your needs. Version 1.2 has changes in syntax that will prevent the code from the course compile. Hegarty will stick with the public releases during the course.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, but i want to build an social network app and now with 1.2 it's much easier to work with JSONs i guess.